# PHP page loads blank when a variable is passed through the URL

Tags: javascript, php, url, get

Basically I have a work log page where you review tasks for a certain department which you select from a drop-down of departments. Basically when a different department is selected in the drop down I am sending the DeptID based off the department selected to the url - review_tasks.php?DeptID=12 which uses following javascript:

```
    $(".Department").bind('change',function()
    {
    var department = $(this).attr("value");
    window.location.href="review_tasks.php?DeptID=" + department;
    }
```

As for my PHP code I am using the following to try and retrieve the value from URL

```
if (isset($_GET['DeptID']))
{
$DeptID = $_GET['DeptID'];
set_DeptID($DeptID);    
}
```

My problem is when a new department is selected I get a blank page instead of a bunch of new work logs for that department I just selected. The URL string appears correct without any spaces like this review_tasks.php?DeptID=12. Any Ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

I get the following errors, ignore the ones regarding FormScrubber.php:

Notice: Undefined index: Action in /www/applications/appsdev/htdocs/was/wcm/Config/wcm.php on line 715 Notice: Undefined index: DeptID in /www/applications/appsdev/htdocs/was/wcm/Config/wcm.php on line 928 Warning: require_once(FormScrubber.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/applications/appsdev/htdocs/was/wcm/Config/wcm.php on line 208 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'FormScrubber.php' (include_path='.:/www/applications/library') in /www/applications/appsdev/htdocs/was/wcm/Config/wcm.php on line 208

Code near line 715:

```
    if (strlen(Trim($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) > 1) 
    {
        $queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
        $newVars = array();
        parse_str($queryString, $newVars);

        if ($newVars['Action'] == 'logout')
        {
            // Unset all of the session variables.
            $_SESSION = array();

            // destroy the session.
            session_destroy();;
            header("Location: index.php?r=logout");
            exit();
        }
    }
```

Code Near Line 928:

```
    function get_DeptID()
    {
$_SESSION['WCM_Message'] = "";
$queryString = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$newVars = array();
parse_str($queryString, $newVars);
$DeptID_querystr = $newVars['DeptID'];

$DeptID_value = $_SESSION['WCM_DeptID'];
$PeopleID = $_SESSION['WCM_PeopleID'];
$access_level = get_access_level();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess the function:

```
set_DeptID($DeptID);
```

...isn't defined or is throwing an error. Try adding this to the top of your PHP script for debugging:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: It seems to work fine when I navigate from another page which uses $_POST to set DeptID. How would I set it through post when someone changes the drop down?

Comment: instead of $_GET['yourvar'] see if it works with $_REQUEST['yourvar'];

Comment: It might also be worth calling print_r($_GET);exit; to debug what your $_GET array actually contains

Comment: I get these errors, ignore FormScrubber.php: Notice: Undefined index: Action in /www/applications/appsdev/htdocs/was/wcm/Config/wcm.php on line 715 Notice: Undefined index: DeptID in /www/applications/appsdev/htdocs/was/wcm/Config/wcm.php on line 928 Warning: require_once(FormScrubber.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /www/applications/appsdev/htdocs/was/wcm/Config/wcm.php on line 208 Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'FormScrubber.php' (include_path='.:/www/applications/library') in /www/applications/appsdev/htdocs/was/wcm/Config/wcm.php on line 208

Comment: The last one is your problem: That fatal error is crashing your page. It can't find your file "FormScrubber.php"

Comment: Thanks, since I didn't write the original code I ended up just commenting out the portion with FormScrubber since I have no idea what server it was stored on - after I commented it out my $_GET worked just fine and my page works now.

Answer (score 2):

When you check you write `$_GET['DeptID']` but you try to get the value from `$_GET['Department']`.

Comment: That wasn't it, I just forgot to write DeptID in the php here when I posted the question. I wish it was that easy...

Comment: Blank page generally means error. Have you checked the error logs?